# Checking if the language code is valid or not with googletrans module

Tags: python, google-translate

I have tried this code

```py
import googletrans
import bookDescription

bookList = ["Harry Potter", "The Alchemist", "The Hound of The Baskervilles", "Rich Dad Poor Dad"]

bookDescriptionDict = {
    bookList[0]: bookDescription.harry_potter,
    bookList[1]: bookDescription.the_alchemist,
    bookList[2]: bookDescription.the_hound_of_the_baskervilles,
    bookList[3]: bookDescription.rich_dad_and_poor_dad,
}

def checkForValidLanguageCode(langCode):
    if langCode in googletrans.LANGCODES[langCode]:
        return True
    return False

preferedLangCodeInp = input("Enter the language you prefer to read in (Language Codes only): ")
isValid = checkForValidLanguageCode(preferedLangCodeInp)

if isValid:
    print(f"Ok, you preferred language is {googletrans.LANGCODES[preferedLangCodeInp]}.")
else:
    print("That's not a valid language code!")
```

Let me explain this a little bit
I have a list of books and a dictionary with their description. bookDescription is a little file with the descriptions. Now, I want to use the `checkForValidLanguageCode` function to check if the langCode param is a valid language code or not. So, when I take input and I enter `en`, it gives me this error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Skillathon-Projects\help-your-friends\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    isValid = checkForValidLanguageCode(preferedLangCodeInp)
  File "C:\Users\DEBARKA NASKAR\Desktop\Skillathon-Projects\help-your-friends\main.py", line 14, in checkForValidLanguageCode   
    if langCode in googletrans.LANGCODES[langCode]: return True
KeyError: 'en'
```

Why am I getting this error? I don't understand. Any help is appreciated :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the given language code is present, you can try the following code:

```
import googletrans
import bookDescription

preferedLang=''
bookList = ["Harry Potter", "The Alchemist", "The Hound of The Baskervilles", "Rich Dad Poor Dad"]

bookDescriptionDict = {
    bookList[0]: bookDescription.harry_potter,
    bookList[1]: bookDescription.the_alchemist,
    bookList[2]: bookDescription.the_hound_of_the_baskervilles,
    bookList[3]: bookDescription.rich_dad_and_poor_dad,
}

def checkForValidLanguageCode(langCode):
    data=googletrans.LANGCODES
    for key, value in data.items():
        if value == langCode:
            global preferedLang
            preferedLang=key
            return True
    return False

preferedLangCodeInp = input("Enter the language you prefer to read in (Language Codes only): ")
isValid = checkForValidLanguageCode(preferedLangCodeInp)

if isValid:
    print(f"Ok, you preferred language is {preferedLang}.")
else:
    print("That's not a valid language code!")
```

In your code, you are trying to pass language code as an argument in ‘googletrans.LANGCODES[langCode]’. The `googletrans.LANGCODES` returns the JSON that contains the key as language name and value as language code.

Comment: Ah, it returns JSON. I thought it returns a normal Python Dictionary haha

Comment: And is there an way to return the actual language name? Because it's returning the language code right now.

Comment: @arandomnoob. This code returns the actual language name of the language code.